# How to understand 'means of...' in this sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context

Today I read a sentence in an answer choice of a GRE Reading passage:

> (E) The structure of male cycad cones is consistent with a certain
> means of cycad pollination, but that means is inconsistent with the
> structure of most female cycad cones.

I am confused to understand the meaning of **...means of**，I checked the Merriam-Webster online dictionary and found no clue. Please help. Thank you!

Comment: a means of pollination; the resources to pollinate.

Comment: "means of (achieving a goal)" is equivalent to "method/process by which (a goal) is achieved"

Comment: Thank you for your replies.  I rechecked the merriam-Webster the meaning should be below:  2.  means plural in form but singular or plural in construction: something useful or helpful to a desired end